# Reading the content of property file in Spring Validator Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.0. Can i read a property file from a localdrive eg: C:\prop\mylogin.properties(not under webapps/application server)

**mylogin.properties**

```
login.heading=Login
login.username=Username
login.password_blank=Password cannot be blank
```

I want to use the above in my Validator class(java bean class). 
Please Note : I using MultiAction Controller not SpringFormController

```
 public class MyUserValidator implements Validator 
    {

@Override
    public void validate(Object command, Errors errors) {
         String msg=null;
     //some conditions checked
         String msg=login.password_blank;-------->get from property file ??
        errors.rejectValue("User",msg,"defaultvalue");   

}
```

Hi we are using resource bundle, not sure how this will need to be used within validator?

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" lazy-init="true"> 
       <property name="basenames"> 
       <list> 

      <value>${deployment.properties.path}/xyzsite/mylogin</value>   

 </list> 
 </property> 
<property name="cacheSeconds" value="${deployment.properties.cache_in_seconds}"/> 
</bean>
```

What change i cud make in the answer u have mentioned if resource bundle is been used?

for example if i want to set a PageSize
int pagesize=5; ---> get this from property file

**mylogin.properties**

```
login.heading=Login
login.username=Username
login.password_blank=Password cannot be blank
login.page_row_size=5
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright got this sorted by doing following 
mav= new ModelAndView
mav.addAllObjects(errors.getModel());

and in jsp using

Answer (score 2):

Error messages are usually best handled as a standard combination of a Java `ResourceBundle` and JSTL, but that won't work for loading the properties from an arbitrary location on the filesystem.

So you'll have to do things a bit more manually. The simplest thing would be to inject the location of the properties file, then extract the properties from it:

```
public class MyUserValidator implements Validator {

    private Resource propertiesLocation;

    @Required
    public void setPropertiesLocation(Resource propertiesLocation) {
        this.propertiesLocation = propertiesLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object command, Errors errors) {
        try {
            Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(propertiesLocation);

            String key = "login.password_blank";
            String errorMessage = props.getProperty(key);
            errors.rejectValue("User", key, errorMessage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle me
        }
    }
}
```

and in the config:

```
<bean id="userValidator" class="com.x.MyUserValidator">
  <property name="propertiesLocation" value="file:/prop/mylogin.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Note the following line:

```
errors.rejectValue("User", key, errorMessage);
```

Since you're not using `ResourceBundle`, you need to pass in the "default error message" as the 3rd argument.